# Is it possible to work with a Sybase DB natively in Doctrine 2?

Tags: doctrine-orm, sybase

We are currently running a website that uses pdo_odbc and ADOdb Active Record as ORM when working with our Sybase database. We are trying to use Doctrine 2 but we realize that it does not support ODBC neither Sybase natively.

Do you have any idea if there is a way to solve this problem in Doctrine 2 without having to code a Sybase driver from zero?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly you are out of luck.

Coding your own driver is the only way, as stated [here](http://groups.google.com/group/doctrine-user/browse_thread/thread/7ea1b58982eb2377) there are no plans for implementing new drivers which are not actively used by the current developers.

Comment: Thanks Jere! I hope this would change in the future as we have no intention in coding a new driver for now.

Answer (score 0):

Use Devart Driver to make a PDO odbc connection with Sybase.

create Devart Driver in System DSN in ODBC Datasource administrator

To achive doctrine, pass connection Object to doctrine parameters