# how do I connect Sybase to zendframework 3?

Tags: sybase, zend-framework3

I can't connect Sybase to zf3. but I can connect core PHP.

```
$Appname = basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'], ".php");
    $Dsquery = getenv("DSQUERY");
    $Dbname = "tempdb";
    $Username = "sa";
    $Passwd = "xxxxxxxx";

$conn = sybase_connect($Dsquery, $Username, $Passwd);
```

It was able to connect with core PHP and Sybase.

Let me know how to connect with ZF3 below.

```
return [
    'doctrine' => [
        'connection' => [
            'orm_default' => [
                'driverClass' => PDOMySqlDriver::class,
                'params' => [
                    'host'     => 'localhost',                    
                    'user'     => 'root',
                    'password' => '1234',
                    'dbname'   => 'test_db',
                ]
            ],            
        ],        
    ],
    'db' => [
        'driver' => 'Mysqli',
        'database' => 'test_db',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '1234',
    ],
];
```

Comment: You look to be using a MySQL driver in your ZF3 example so the first thing would be to ensure you use the correct driver.

Comment: I am using devart odbc connection for sybase. which is working for core php.

$conn = odbc_connect("DRIVER={Devart ODBC Driver for ASE};Server=Develop;Database=poc7", "sa", "");

But i want it in ZF3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.We have installed Devart to make a PDO odbc connection with Sybase.

2.Need to create Devart Driver in System DSN in ODBC Datasource administrator

3.Then in zend3 we used pdo connection with devart odbc.

4.To achive doctrine, we passed connection Object to doctrine parameters.

```
<?php
use Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver as PDOMySqlDriver;
$connPdo = null;

try {
    $connPdo = new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Devart ODBC Driver for ASE};host=Develop;dbname=poc;charset=utf8", "sa", "");
    $connPdo->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . '</br>';
}
return [
    'doctrine' => [
        'connection' => [
            'orm_default' => [
                'driverClass' => PDOMySqlDriver::class,
                'params' => [
                    'pdo' => $connPdo
                ]
            ],            
        ],        
    ],
];
```

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](https://www.doctrine-project.org/2010/02/11/database-support-doctrine2.html) says, there is no support official for SYBASE yet in doctrine.

Someone else asked here as well: [Is it possible to work with a Sybase DB natively in Doctrine 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9211085/is-it-possible-to-work-with-a-sybase-db-natively-in-doctrine-2)

However if you look on GitHub someone added support: https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/pull/2347

As you can see, it's failing. But of course you can give it a try and maybe fix it yourself.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Use DBLIB drivers, which are free and efficient. Use the code below.

> $connPdo = new PDO("dblib:host=localhost;dbname=dbname;", "username", "password");